# Android MediaPlayer - how to play in the STREAM_ALARM?

Tags: android, stream, media-player, android-audiomanager

I've tried settings the audio stream of the media player in my application using the following code but when I do this I hear no sound in the emulator. If I don't set the stream for the player then the audio plays fine. I'm sure I'm using this wrong but cannot workout how, any help?

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.test_audio);

AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM), AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
player.start();
```

Note: I've added the MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission to my manifest already.

Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

I don't know why this would happen, however the code below works. You should set the data source with `setDataSource()` instead of with `create()`.

This code works:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
mp.setDataSource(this,Uri.parse("android.resource://PACKAGE_NAME/"+R.raw.soundfile));
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

This code *doesn't* work:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soundfile);
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: better to write the uri like: `Uri.parse("android.resource://"+mContext.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.sound)`

Answer (score 6):

The issue is you are using `MediaPlayer.create()` to create your MediaPlayer. `Create` function calls the `prepare()` function which finalize your media and does not allow you to change `AudioStreamType`.

The solution is using `setDataSource` instead of `create`:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
mp.setLooping(true);
try {
   mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), yourAudioUri);
   mp.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
mp.start();
```

See [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20int)) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

The solution here was deprecated in API 22

I opened my own [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881732/playing-sound-on-the-alarm-channel-on-android/50881793#50881793) to figure this out.

Here is an updated working solution.

```
mediaPlayerScan = new MediaPlayer();
try {
  mediaPlayerScan.setDataSource(getContext(),
          Uri.parse(getString(R.string.res_path) + R.raw.scan_beep));

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    mediaPlayerScan.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .build());
  } else {
    mediaPlayerScan.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
  }
  mediaPlayerScan.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Found a simplier way (for SDK >= 21):

`MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.<sound>, new 
    AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM).build(), audioManager.generateAudioSessionId());`

Answer (score 2):

1.
setAudioStreamType(int streamtype)

Must call this method before prepare() ;

2.
MediaPlayer.create(Context context, int resid)

On success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be called again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

And why are you calling "audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);"? The value isn't stored in a variable, so it is rather useless ;)

I hope that helped

Comment: I tried it with player.prepare() but it didn't make any difference. Still no audio played. I was storing the the stream volume to a variable which is used later in my app, I took out the assignment temporarily to help with debugging.