# MediaPlayer: how to Play in STREAM_ALARM

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-securityexception

I am beginner in android development. I need to play media from raw file as STREAM_ALARM for my alarm clock. I found a similar question here :
[Android MediaPlayer - how to play in the STREAM_ALARM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057115/android-mediaplayer-how-to-play-in-the-stream-alarm)

The accepted answer was like that on that link:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
mp.setDataSource(this,Uri.parse("android.resource://PACKAGE_NAME/"+R.raw.soundfile));
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

My project's first line is like this:

```
package buet.mushfiq.classfriendsupport;
```

So, I used buet.mushfiq.classfriendsupport as my project name and implemented code in this way:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://buet.mushfiq.classfriendsupport/"+R.raw.mytone);
MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
try{
    mp.setDataSource(this,uri);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();}
catch (Exception e){
    }
```

But unfortunately no audio plays and android studio shows this error:

```
setDataSource IOException | SecurityException happend: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No package found for authority: 
android.resource://buet.mushfiq.classfriendsupport/2131099648
```

mytone.mp3 is surely present in raw folder. Actual location: app/src/main/res/raw. Android studio plays media finely when I apply this code:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mytone);
mp.start();
```

So how can I locate my file in Uri.parse function?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://buet.mushfiq.classfriendsupport/"+R.raw.mytone);
```

to

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.mytone);
```

hope then it will working fine. thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have saved my work. simple edit: add () after getPackageName.